# Submit data as JsonNode

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, jax-rs

I have a springboot application. I want to have a REST method that takes JsonNode as an argument! But When I try to submit a html form it gives below error...

Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException

Below is my rest method in controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action", method = RequestMethod.POST,             
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, 
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String action(JsonNode data) {
```

Thank you

Comment: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html JsonNode is Abstract as the error suggests. Additionally why would you bind your API to a 3rd Party class? Much better to actually accept an expected model. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish by tying yourself directly to a jackson class and making your clients have to write the required body to fulfill what the concrete JsonNodes expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add @RequestBody to the argument it will work:

```
public String action( @RequestBody JsonNode data) {
```